How to tell what consumes disk time (disk active time 100%)
There's a lot of answers how to tell what creates a load to a disk (check total i/o, use resmon etc) but questions how to tell what consumes 100% disk time are unaswered.
Let's put it this way. When I start a search for a file or a folder with, let's say, Total Commander, my Disk Activity Time goes up to 100%. What tool can show me it's Total Commander creates this load on the disk?
Once again, I'm not looking for the tool can show me what program does heavy write / read load on the disk, like, let's say, disk benchmarks or file copying create. See, my i/o to the disk is very low, but disk activity time is 100% while searching. I need to know what process creates this 100% Disk Activity Time.


Assuming it's Windows (should be specifically mentioned in question or tag), use Task Manager on Details tab, and add disk I/O Reads and Writes to columns. That said, how have you configure Search Indexing??
